# Response Spectrum - how to get data from website

Tags: http-headers, httpclient, httpresponse

Please is anybody help me or at least explain, how it works...

It's about this website: http://mpk.wroc.pl/jak-jezdzimy/mapa-pozycji-pojazdow

when click on <kbd>F12</kbd>, we can seeing, that we have

[image]

and if typing in cmd command, e.g.:

```
curl http://mpk.wroc.pl/position.php --data \
  "busList%5Btram%5D%5B%5D=31&busList%5Btram%5D%5B%5D=32"
```

it everythings works!

[image]

also is appears from "response" on developer mode.

[image]

but finally, when I wanted get data by Postman, setting `POST` and sending correct data (I think), it returns nothing...

also I tried made by C# by `HTTPClient`, `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`/`Response` etc. and nothing, I can't found any data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:
Create new Postrequest in postman to http://mpk.wroc.pl/position.php
Change body keyvalues in x-www-form-urlencode.

http://prntscr.com/le1deh

**EDIT**

To implement this in C# you can do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> formvalues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formvalues.Add("busList[bus][]", "114");
        FormUrlEncodedContent body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formvalues);
        sendPost(body);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static async void sendPost(FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://mpk.wroc.pl/position.php", content);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
```

Comment: Ohh, Thank You, good Man :)
Could you explain me, how to handle in c# by http client or something like this ? Please it is imortant :)

Comment: How do you know that? :O You are awesome, thank you, I would give you more votes if I could :)